# Get all the orders of the seller and sort it by date?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, backend, mern

How can I get all the orders from the seller and then sort them by the previous date to the present?

This is what I get for all transactions, when I Order.find(),

```
[
    {
        "_id": "636357777877c919bb2cfa45",
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": "636355a07877c919bb2cdfdc",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": "636355187877c919bb2cdf1f",
                "_id": "636357777877c919bb2cfa46"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 100,
        "createdAt": "2022-10-03T05:53:59.997Z",
     
    },
    {
        "_id": "636357da7877c919bb2d035f",
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": "636357387877c919bb2cf494",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": "636355187877c919bb2cdf1f",
                "_id": "636357da7877c919bb2d0360"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 100,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-03T05:55:38.858Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-03T05:55:38.858Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "636367d2407816df5f589bc6",
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": "63635acf7877c919bb2d3d95",
                "quantity": 1,
                "sellerId": "636355187877c919bb2cdf1f",
                "_id": "636367d2407816df5f589bc7"
            }
        ],
        "amount": 20,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-03T07:03:46.350Z",
    }
]
```

So what I'm trying to get here is the total amount of the seller during a certain month. For example, I have 3 orders here, one of them is from October, while the other two are from November.

So the output should be.

```
October = 100
November = 120
```

I tried the code below, but I received an empty array

This is my URL

> http://localhost:5000/api/order/previousSales/636355187877c919bb2cdf1f

```
router.get('/previousSales/:id', async (req,res) => {
    const {id} = req.params
    const date = new Date();
    const lastMonth = new Date(date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1));
    const previousMonth = new Date(new Date().setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1)); 

    try {
      const order = await Order.aggregate([
        {
          $match: {
            createdAt: {gte: previousMonth}, ...(id && {
              products: {$elemMatch: {id}}
            })

          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            month: { $month: "$createdAt" },
            sales: "$amount",
          },
        },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$month",
            total: { $sum: "$sales" },
          },
        },
        
      ])  
      res.status(200).json(order)
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).json({message: error.message})
    }

  })
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that the Object Id in URL belongs to the **sellerId** inside the **product array.**

Comment: Can the `products` array contain more than one product? Can it contain more than one `sellerId`?

Comment: its fine, i'm just trying to get the products related to the sellerId, Then I'll combine all the products which is ordered at the same month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `$match` step to this:

```
  {$match: {
      createdAt: {$gte: previousMonth},
      products: {$elemMatch: {sellerId: id}}
  }},
```

Since currently you are looking for the field `id` but you want to look for the field `sellerId`.

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zFU0EEuw6CE)